# What happens when you deal damage with a raise but the victim is already shaken?

Tags: savage-worlds, shaken

Let's say a wild card foe gets shaken (either through damage or other means). Per the rules, if she gets "shaken again" through successful damage, she gets a wound instead (and remains shaken).

What if a PC successfully hits her and beats her toughness with a raise (instead of simply beating it)? Does the foe get one wound or two wounds (one for being shaken again and the other for the raise)?

Comment: See this meta post -http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/shaken-tag-for-savage-worlds - for discussion about the Shaken tag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The process for determining whether a target hit for damage is shaken and/or wounded can be summed up as follows:

If the target is not Shaken

- A success on the damage roll = Shaken
- 1 Raise = 1 Wound and Shaken
- 2 Raises = 2 Wounds and Shaken
- 3 Raises = 3 Wounds and Shaken
- And so on...

If the target is Shaken

- Success = 1 Wound and remains Shaken
- Raise = 1 Wound and remains Shaken
- 2 Raises = 2 Wounds and remains Shaken
- 3 Raises = 3 Wounds and remains Shaken
- And so on...

The important part (and where a lot of players get it wrong) is how a success and the first raise affect a target that is already shaken.  The reason for the game being designed like this has been explained as 'because it makes it easier for a Shaken Wildcard to be wounded but not *seriously* wounded'.

See [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30359) for an official take on this subject, which gets asked A LOT on the official forums.

An additional post with a more detailed breakdown can be found [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33174&highlight=shaken%20wound).

Comment: Yep. The important passage in *Explorer's Edition* is on p. 75, bottom of the left column: "If a [Wild Card] is already Shaken, he suffers a wound as usual, but this isn’t cumulative. Wild Cards only suffer **one wound per raise whether they are Shaken or not**." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score -4):

The way I simplify it is that you count the success and each raise as a wound. If the target is not shaken, the first wound causes the target to be shaken instead. Also, I make the shaking flavoursome, such as "you panic as your sleeve catches fire."

So in your case, you roll a raise: two wounds. If the target is already shaken, they receive two wounds. If the target is not shaken, they become shaken and take one wound.

Note that it's possible to roll multiple raises on a damage roll, resulting in several simultaneous wounds.

Comment: I thought that too, but it seemed a little harsh. Is it in the the rules?

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but if I understand what you are saying, this is NOT correct.  A Shaken target you hit with a raise on the damage roll only takes 1 wound and remains shaken - see my answer below.

Comment: @Phil, thanks, that's interesting!  I might start playing like that.